# Кирилические символы при отправке письма искажаются

Tags: oracle, plsql

При отправке письма на почту Outlook из Oracle СУБД, в котором содержатся кириллические символы, на выходе знаки вопросов.

Не пойму, как преобразовать строку, чтобы текст был читаемый.

Отправку осуществляю следующим способом:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, 'Привет мир!' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

---

PS: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обшщем случае, тело письма может содержать только 7-битные символы US7ASCII.
Поэтому, содержимое, включающее символы отличные от US7ASCII, должно быть закодировано как *quoted-printable* или *base-64*, и об этом следует указать в заголовке письма. В [документации](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAY0p.png) сказано следующее:

> Text (`VARCHAR2`) data sent using `WRITE_DATA` *is converted to US7ASCII before it is sent*. If the text contains multibyte characters, *each multibyte character in the text that cannot be converted to US7ASCII is **replaced by a '?' character***. If 8BITMIME extension is negotiated with the SMTP server using the EHLO subprogram, multibyte VARCHAR2 data can be sent by first converting the text to RAW using the `UTL_RAW` package, and then sending the RAW data using `WRITE_RAW_DATA`.

Минимальный пример рутины будет выглядеть так:

```sql
create or replace procedure sendMail (
        sendto varchar2, sendfrom varchar2, subj varchar2, msg varchar2, 
        host VARCHAR2, port number := 25) as
    conn utl_smtp.connection;
begin
    conn := utl_smtp.open_connection (host, port);
    utl_smtp.helo (conn, host);
    utl_smtp.mail (conn, sendfrom);
    utl_smtp.rcpt (conn, sendto);
    utl_smtp.open_data (conn);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'Subject: '||subj||UTL_TCP.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'MIME-version: 1.0'||UTL_TCP.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'    ||UTL_TCP.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'||UTL_TCP.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_raw_data (conn, 
        utl_encode.quoted_printable_encode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw (msg)));
    utl_smtp.close_data (conn);
    utl_smtp.quit (conn);
end;
/

exec sendMail ('me', 'send-mail', 'test cyrillic', 'Привет мир!', 'localhost')
```

Результат в сыром виде:

```
Subject: test cyrillic
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
[...]
From: send-mail@mx.local.net

=D0=9F=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=BC=D0=B8=D1=80!
```

Результат в почтовом клиенте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало!